# Errors were encountered while processing: wps-office

Tags: software-uninstall, wps-office

I am using ubuntu subsystem for windows. I am trying to remove wps-office which for some reason I tried to install way before. I am trying to remove it with

```
sudo apt-get purge wps-office
```

However I am getting the error below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
 wps-office*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 386 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 83671 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wps-office (10.1.0.5707~a21) ...
xdg-mime: file '/usr/share//mime/packages/wps-office-et.xml' does not exist
dpkg: error processing package wps-office (--purge):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
  wps-office
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*Any suggestions ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, run:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/desktop-directories/
sudo touch /usr/share//mime/packages/wps-office-et.xml
sudo apt-get purge wps-office
```